# Escape FTP password with special characters via CLI

Tags: command-line, ftp, escaping

Trying to use Grunt FTP deploy plugin. Have an FTP password with the characters !,@,%,# and can't seem to find which of and how these need to be escaped.

I've tried wrapping the entire password string in single-quotes and \ escaping each character. In the former case I still get and auth failed error; in the latter case, I get an error like "Unexpected token @".

Comment: have you tried to use single or double quotes without escaping the special characters?

Comment: I've tried single quotes, double quotes and \ escaping. Nothing works. It's a Windows server, which I'm not sure makes any difference, and I'm able to connect using an FTP client with the straight password.

Comment: assuming your password would be #p@ss%ord! - what exactly would you do?

Comment: I have tried '#p@ss%ord!', "#p@ss%ord!" (with these quotes escaped for JSON) and \ escaping all and each of the special characters.

Comment: You say "these quotes escaped for JSON" - what exactly does that mean? The second string should work just like that: `{"key1":{"username": "username1", "password": "#p@ss%ord!"}}` There should be no need of \ escaping anything other than double-quotes inside the password, if they do exist.

Comment: maybe the password string is not the problem, is the whole .ftppass file valid json? Maybe you just forgot a comma or something. You better double check with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) or similar ;)

Comment: .ftppass is valid JSON. Again, this works with creds for another server. I can't use these credentials with a straight cli ftp either, but it works in FTP clients. As for escaping quotes I had tried `{"key1":{"username": "username1", "password": "\"#p@ss%ord!\""}}` as well as the above as well as several other things.

Comment: hmm, then it's probably a bug in the grunt-ftp plugin that [you might want to submit](https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy/issues/new?title=Special+characters+in+passwords+don%27t+work&body=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726824/).

Comment: That was my first thought until I tried to straight FTP from command line and that failed.

Comment: Just to understand this correctly, 'straigt FTP from command line' would be still using grunt, cause you said it works in 'FTP clients'? Could you post some details on what exactly you're doing?

Comment: php has a function to encode especial characters urlencode($password) if your password would be #p@ss%ord! the encoded version is %23p%40ss%25ord%21

Answer (score 0):

[README.md](https://github.com/zonak/grunt-ftp-deploy/blob/master/README.md#authentication-parameters)

> **IMPORTANT**: make sure that the .ftppass file uses double quotes (which is the [proper JSON syntax](http://www.json.com/#data-types-string)) instead of single quotes for the
>   names of the keys and the string values.

---

> **String**
>   Series of characters (letters, numbers, or symbols); double-quoted
>   UTF-8 with backslash escaping.

Comment: Yes, the JSON is well-formed. All the quoting of the password was done inside the double quotes of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but I just had this problem and finally found a solution.

My CLI is Windows and my problem was related a batch script where the password for my SFTP (using PSFTP) had special charachters.

I solved it escaping the password with the rules described here:
https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

The password was "X5d2KeY6%0123ghjy".
The password became "X5d2KeY6%%0123ghjy" (that is, % became %%).